# JSDoc3 & NodeJS link to types from modules

Tags: node.js, jsdoc

I try to find how to let JSDoc3 automatically generate links to classes from other modules.
I find it hard to explain in words, so let me give some examples. The following script generates the expected output:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
var SomeClass = function(){}

/**
 * @param {SomeClass} someParam description
 */
var someFunc = function(someParam){}
```

That is, JSDoc3 correctly generates a link from the parameter list of someFunc to the class description of SomeClass. However, when I put SomeClass in an external module I can't seem to let JSDoc3 generate the links:

```
/**
 * @file SomeClass.js
 * @module SomeClass
 */

/**
 * @constructor
 */
exports.SomeClass(){}


/**
 * @file main.js
 */
var SomeClass = require('./SomeClass');

/**
 * @param {SomeClass} someParam description
 */
function someFunc(someParam){}
```

Now JSDoc3 correctly generates the documentation for both files, but it doesn't link the parameter type of someFunc to the page of SomeClass. I tried replacing `@param {SomeClass}` with:

- `@param {SomeClass.SomeClass}`
- `@param {SomeClass/SomeClass}`
- `@param {@link SomeClass}`
- `@param {@link SomeClass.SomeClass}`
- `@param {@link SomeClass/SomeClass}`

But none of these worked: in all cases the documentation simply shows the text inside the curly brackets (even when I used @link).

How can I let JSDoc3 correctly generate links to the external modules?

Comment: If You use {{@link SomeCLass}} it attempts to resolve the link, I'm not sure on the proper syntax just yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `module:` prefix when referencing modules. If the module's return value is the class itself, then use `module:SomeClass`. If it is a property of the module, use `module:SomeClass.SomeClass`. The @link tag shouldn't be necessary if jsdoc can find a reference to the existing class documentation.

Comment: Not on topic, but related - How to use the @link tag - Link a class `{@link Class| Class name}`. Link a module`{@link Namespace| Namespace name}`. Link a module (needs prefix)`{@link module:Module| Module name}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `typeof import`

```
    /**
     * @param {typeof import("puppeteer").Browser} browser
     */
```

[Docs here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#import-types)